# How to add comp102x.IO package in BlueJ IDE?

Tags: bluej

Compiler in the Blue J  IDE says it could not find the package `comp102x.IO`. 
How can I add this package to Blue J?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Specifically, what have you tried to do so far to add the package?